# Inverses and Piece-wise functions

Tags: functions

Let $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
k(x) &\text{if }x>2, \\
2+(x-2)^2&\text{if }x\leq2.
\end{cases}$$
Find the function $k(x)$ such that $f$ is its own inverse.

I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by plotting the known part out first, then make a mirror image of that about $y=x$. That should fill the missing portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the given part of your function. Reflect that about $y=x$ will give you the inverse of that part, as well as fill in the missing part, such that $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. That is, the rule of $k(x)$ is the rule of the inverse of $2+(x-2)^2$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are right.